# Инициализация полей в структуре

Tags: c++, структуры

У меня есть структура. Там находится 3 персонажа.
Первого я должен инициализировать с помощью "{}", как в 48 строке. Второго - через указатели на структуру ("->"), третьего - вводит пользователь.
Попытался разобраться с первым ("{}") - потерпел фиаско, ошибку прикреплю ниже. Со вторым даже не знаю что и делать. 
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Строка:

```
student[1] = {"Tymofeenko", "RPZ 18 1/9", 2, 5, 5, 5, "Daniil", "Receptionist"};
```

Ошибка:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct student
{       char surname[21];
        char group[10];
        int course;
        int programming;
        int physics;
        int math;
        // Информация о рабочих
        char WorkersName[20];
        char JobTitle[30];
}; 
void read(student & s)
{       cout << " Surname: ";
        cin >> s.surname;
        cout << "\n Group: ";
        cin >> s.group;
        cout << "\n Course: ";
        cin >> s.course;
        cout << "\n Programming: ";
        cin >> s.programming;
        cout << "\n Physics: ";
        cin >> s.physics;
        cout << "\n Math: ";
        cin >> s.math;
        cout << "\n Worker's Name: ";
        cin >> s.WorkersName;
        cout << "\n Job Title: ";
        cin >> s.JobTitle;
} 
void print(student & s)
{       printf("\t%10s  \t", s.surname);
        printf("\t%10s  \t", s.group);
        printf("\t%1d  \t", s.course);
        printf("\t%1d  \t", s.programming);
        printf("\t%1d  \t", s.physics);
        printf("\t%1d  \t", s.math);
        printf("\t%10s  \t", s.WorkersName);
        printf("\t%10s  \t", s.JobTitle);
}
int main()
{   student *s;
    int n = 3;
    int size;
    cout << endl;
    s = new student [n];
    student[1] = {"Tymofeenko", "RPZ 18 1/9", 2, 5, 5, 5, "Daniil", "Receptionist"};

    cout << "\nVvedit dani\n" ;
    for (int i = 2; i<n; i++)
    {
        read(s[i]);
    }
    printf("Surname:\tGroup:\tCourse:\tProgramming:\tPhysics:\tMath:\tWorkers's Name:\tJob Title:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        print(s[i]);
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Присваивайте по полям, и НЕ ТИПУ, а переменной - наподобие

```
strcpy(s[1].surname,"Timofeenko");
```

Еще - можно создать конструктор типа

```
student(const char * sur, const char * grp, int c, int pr,
        int ph, int m, const char * w, const char * j)
    :course(c),programming(pr),physics(ph),math(m)
{
    strcpy(surname,sur);
    strcpy(group,grp);
    strcpy(WorkersName,w);
    strcpy(JobTitle,j);
}
```

и тогда присваивать как

```
s[1] = student{"Tymofeenko", "RPZ 18 1/9", 2, 5, 5, 5, "Daniil", "Receptionist"};
```